# If $Spec(f)$ is a homeomorphism then what can be said about $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a morphism of rings and suppose that $\text{Spec}(f) : \text{Spec}(B) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(A)$ is a homeomorphism of topological spaces (not necessarily of schemes). What can be said about the original ring map $f$?

Comment: I may be mistaken but I thought that was for affine schemes. I meant as topological spaces only.

Comment: @MoarCake559 There are lots of counterexamples.  For instance, any inclusion of fields induces a homeomorphism on spectra.

Comment: At least, $f$ should be injective as $\text{Spec}(f)(\eta_B) = \eta_A$ where $\eta$ is the generic point.

Comment: @N.H. $A \to A/nil(A)$ is not injective if $A$ is not reduced, but induces a homeomorphism on spectra.

Comment: The correct conclusion is that $\operatorname{ker f}$ is contained in the nil radical of $A$. Thus your claim is true if $A$ is reduced.

Comment: This is better like this, thanks !